# Question related to <select> input field

Tags: javascript, html

I have three `<select>` input fields: `<select name=first>`,`<select name=second>`and`<select name=three>`.
The 2nd and 3rd fields are disabled. If the user changes the value of the first field, the 2nd field should be enabled and so on. Is there an example related to this task? thanks

Comment: Should the second one get enabled when the first value changes?

Comment: I think you are missing words in your sentences ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In its easiest way, you can bind an event handler to the elements for the `change` event and adjust the `disabled` property:

```
var form = document.getElementById('formId');

form.first.onchange = function() {
    form.second.disabled = false;
};

form.second.onchange = function() {
    form.three.disabled = false;
};
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/p9pDs/)

I also suggest to disable the fields via JavaScript, otherwise, if users have JavaScript disabled, they cannot use the form.

Answer (score 2):

This is called cascading select, here are some examples

http://forums.digitalpoint.com/showthread.php?t=703846

http://www.everyweb.ru/wmaster/javas/menu/demo/dynasele.html

http://www.inside-oracle-apex.com/generic-solution-for-cascading-select-listslovs/

http://webdeveloper.earthweb.com/webjs/jsnavigation/item.php/91311